# datatables ajax post causing null value to change to empty string ie. ""

Tags: php, ajax, datatables

```
"ajax": {
    "type": "POST",
    "url" : "fakeControllers/fakeMethod",
    "data": <?=json_encode(['filter'=> NULL])?>
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why my post data in the `fakeMethod` method is `"filter": ""`, and not `"filter": null`.

Does it have to do with the php `echo`?

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: both php and javascript have a concept of `NULL` but they do not translate straight from one to the other. If you send NULL from php it will become an empty string in javascript. If you want that js receives and processes NULL you should probably enclose it in quotes

Comment: I do not believe you can send the **idea** `NULL` through `POST` in JavaScript to a PHP script  --  Because the string `filter` is **defined** --  PHP will just see it as **empty**  --  I believe the same would go for trying to set a `boolean` such as **true** or **false** --  PHP would read it as a `string` and not a `boolean`

Comment: In the php code that reads the data, you could do something like this: `$var = (empty($var)) ? null : $var;` [Test it](https://eval.in/607343). But that's not really the answer to your question...

Comment: @FirstOne exactly what you described is what I have done for my work around but I would love to actually send a NULL value.